# Gradle, Jacoco, Jenkins - How can I get Jenkins to publish the report?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jacoco

I have a jave project, which builds using gradle. It runs a jacocoTestReport task, and the report is created during a build. I have a jenkins job which performs the build, and I would like to know how I can get the jenkins job to then publish the coverage report.

I know there is a jacoco maven plugin, etc, but I would assume that since I am using gradle, that is out the window?

I have gotten this far with google, tutorials, etc - but am stuck on this last little hurdle - if anyone can help, that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [Jenkins JaCoCo Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jacoco). It's build-tool-independent and consumes JaCoCo `*.exec` files
2. Add and configure post-build action "Record JaCoCo coverage report". Detailed instructions on how to set up coverage retrieval and publishing can be found [the official documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jacoco#JaCoCoPlugin-Setupcoverageretrievalandpublishing).

Comment: Is this the only way? We are currently running a jenkins version that is <  2.54 - and that means the jacoco plugin wont get loaded for us. Updating is not a possibility right now.

Comment: Choose plugin version which is compatible with your Jenkins instance: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jacoco/

Comment: this is a possible stupid question - but on that link, how do I know which version is going to be compatible with my jenkins, is there a reference table somewhere?

Comment: that's a tricky question. 1) Jenkins will show a warning, but still new plugin versions may work on old Jenkins instances  2) you can check sources (e.g. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L31). BTW, which Jenkins version do you use?

Comment: I am using 3.32.3 :)

Comment: are you sure this is Jenkins version? the latest one available is 2.107.1: https://jenkins.io/download/

Comment: OOPS! I meant 2.32.3 is my version!

Comment: Please use version 2.2.1: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jacoco/2.2.1/jacoco.hpi. It should work for your Jenkins instance

Comment: Thankyou! I will try this in the morning! Marking as best answer for now anyways! May I ask how you worked out the correct version? For future reference?

Comment: 1. Check: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L31
2. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/plugin/3.2 -> `jenkins.version > 2.60.1` - it's higher than Jenkins version, need to use older versions
3. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/commit/d04b50962a022b615d5085271f1696d9f6080198#diff-600376dffeb79835ede4a0b285078036 > 1.625.3
4. highest `jacoco-plugin` version is 2.2.1

Comment: it looks a bit chaotic, comments don't allow to provide well-structured answers

Comment: Thankyou so much!